# Don't click element if it's not displayed on page

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a page where I can have items."Select all" button is visible only if items exist and there is not "Select all" button if there are no items. I have code to click "Select all" if I have items (button exists) and redirect if items count==0 (button doensn't exist):

```
public void ClickSelectAllItemsButton()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("select-all"));
            if (element.Enabled && element.Displayed)
            {
                element.Click();
            }
            else {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://some-url.com");
            }

        }
```

This code work fine if there are some items but if I have 0 items, my test fails because 'else' block is not working. What am I doing wrong?
p.s. Webdriver is working fine and there is no compile errors

Comment: Possibly because the if statement isn't asking enough, maybe do a check to see if you have any items, if true then do your if-else block

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no "Select all" element `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("select-all"))` throws exception.
There are several ways to fix this. The simplest is to use `driver.FindElements` since it returns a list of web elements. In case element exists the list is not empty, otherwise it returns an empty list.
So we can check if the list is empty or not as following:

```
public void ClickSelectAllItemsButton()
    {
    var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("select-all"));    
    if (elements.Count>0 && elements[0].Enabled && elements[0].Displayed)
    {
        elements[0].Click();
    }
    else {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://some-url.com");
    }
}
```